# Regular Expression for Ruby Integer

Tags: ruby, regex

Ruby integers are written as using an optional leading sign, an optional base indicator (0 for octal, 0x for hex, or 0b for binary), followed by a string of digits in the appropriate base. Underscore characters are ignored in the digit string. The letters mentioned in the above description may be either upper or lower case and the underscore characters can only occur strictly within the digit string.

I need to create regular expression to check for Ruby integers in java string with the specification mentioned above.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a Regular Expression Order Service :) You need to share some work of yours about it.

Comment: @mertyildiran, the OP is only expected to describe efforts he or she has made to solve the problem when it's a homework problem. Keep in mind also that many SO members may read this question in future and learn something from the answers.

Comment: Your question is unclear: you say you "need to create regular expression", so why don't you just do it? And what does "check for Ruby integers in java string" mean? Are you talking about somebody accidentally using Ruby numeric literals inside a piece of Java code and you want to find them? Are you talking about a Java regex?

Comment: Note that Ruby does not permit `_2` or `3_`.

Comment: A sample of a typical string would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the substrings that may represent integers are separated by spaces or begin or end the string. If so, I suggest you split the string on whitespace and then the use the method [Kernel#Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) to determine if each element of the resulting array represents an integer.

```
def str_to_int(str)
  str.split.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
    val = Integer(s) rescue nil
    a << [s, val] unless val.nil?
  end
end

str_to_int "22 -22 077     0xAB 0xA_B 0b101 -0b101 cat _3 4_"
  #=> [["22", 22], ["-22", -22], ["077", 63], ["0xAB", 171],
  #    ["0xA_B", 171], ["0b101", 5], ["-0b101", -5]]
```

`Integer` raises a `TypeError` exception is the number cannot be converted to an integer. I've dealt with that with an in-line rescue that returns `nil`, but you may wish to write it so that only that exception is rescued. It may be prudent remove punctuation from the string before executing the above method.

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures positive or negative numbers in denary, binary, octal and hexidecimal form including any underscores:

```
#           hexidecimal                                             binary                     octal                         denary
-?0x[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F_]*[0-9a-fA-F]|-?0x[0-9a-fA-F]|-?0b[01][01_]*[01]|-?0b[01]|-?0[0-7][0-7_]?[0-7]?|-?0[0-7]|-?[1-9][0-9_]*[0-9]|-?[0-9]
```

You should test the regex thoroughly to make sure it works as required but it does seem to work on a few relevant samples I tried (see this on [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/Nc9yiq2dEe) where I've used `()` captures so you can see the matches more easily but it is essentially the same regex).

Here is an example of the regex in action using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
str = "-0x88339_43 wor0ds 8_8_ 0b1001 01words0x334 _9 0b1 0x4 0_ 0x_ 0b_1 0b00_1"
reg = /-?0x[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F_]*[0-9a-fA-F]|-?0x[0-9a-fA-F]|-?0b[01][01_]*[01]|-?0b[01]|-?0[0-7][0-7_]?[0-7]?|-?0[0-7]|-?[1-9][0-9_]*[0-9]|-?[0-9]/
#regex matches
str.scan reg
#=>["-0x88339_43", "0", "8_8", "0b1001", "01", "0x334", "9", "0b1", "0x4", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0b00_1"]
```

Like @CarySwoveland, I'm assuming your string has spaces. Without spaces you will still get a result but it may not be what you desire, but at least it's a start.